# How to pass mutliple $scope values in ng-repeat angularjs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my json data:

```
{
    "seendata": {
        "count": 2,
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "contactCount": 2,
                "group": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "groupname": "group1",
                    "createdAt": "2017-11-16T10:53:12.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-11-16T10:53:12.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "alldata": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "groupname": "group1",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-16T10:53:12.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-16T10:53:12.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "groupname": "group2",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-16T10:54:41.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-16T10:54:41.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

My api code:

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
var globalObj={};
    ContactGroup.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('group.id')),
            'contactCount'
        ]],
        include: [{
            model: Group,
        }],
    }).then(seenData => { globalObj.seendata=seenData;return Group.findAll();})
    .then(function (data) {
globalObj.alldata=data;
        return res.status(200).send(globalObj);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```

And my angular client side controller code:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/getnewgroup'
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.groups = response.data.seendata.rows;
        $scope.alldata = response.data.alldata;
        console.log($scope.groups);
      }, function (response) {
        window.location.href = '/';
      });
```

And my Jade file:

```
tr(ng-repeat='group in groups')
 td {{group.groupname}}
 td {{group.contactCount}}
```

I want to display **contactCount** value as well as i want to display **alldata.groupname** values in my front end?

Help me!

I am getting {{group.contactCount}} correctly, but i am not getting {{group.groupname}} coming from **alldata.groupname**

How to get? both values and how to pass multiple scopes and to be used in ng-repeat?

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: you need to assign alldata to $scope. you are taking only rows from response.

Comment: ok i will take, but how to pass two scope datas inside? ng-repeat? can you help me by posting any snippet in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Better take allData in to $scope.alldata = response.data.alldata;

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/getnewgroup'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.groups = response.data.seendata.rows;
      $scope.allData = response.data.alldata;
      console.log($scope.groups);
    }, function (response) {
      window.location.href = '/';
    });
```

And in your Jade file

```
<tr ng-repeat='group in groups track by $index'>
  <td>
    <span ng-repeat='data in alldata'>data.groupname</span>
  </td>
  <td>group.contactCount</td>
</tr>
```

With help of rows $index you can fetch the data of allData also. Hope it will work

Comment: its not $scope.allData= response.data.seendata.alldata;   $scope.allData= response.data.alldata;   see my json, its not working bro, help me

Comment: make it $scope.allData = response.data.alldata;

Comment: i got contactCount and groupname which is located inside row:, but i dont get groupname which located inside alldata :(

Comment: Debugging process first print {{allData}} is it coming on screen like object

Comment: in Jade
step 1:  td {{allData}} ---> coming
step 2: print $index
step 3: {{allData[$index]}}
step 4: {{allData[$index].groupname}}

Comment: in Jade step `1: td {{allData}} ---> coming step 2: print $index step 3: {{allData[$index]}} step 4: {{allData[$index].groupname}}`

Comment: After step4 im getting "group1", but i need to show "group1" and "group2"

Comment: Then loop allData also using ng-repeat `ng-repeat data in allData` <span>data.groupName</span>

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and show completely? i am a newbie? please

Comment: Now i am getting three groups in table like group1group2group3, i want to display it as separate td?, i Want in tr